# iOS - Globally change navigation bar title color using appearance?

Tags: ios

This crashes the app:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Is there a way to do this using appearance?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This worked:

```
NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];
```

Comment: Works well. If you need to also set the theme to the active UINavigationBar, add this line:
`[yourViewController.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions]`

Comment: UITextAttributeTextColor and UITextAttributeTextShadowColor are deprecated from iOS 7.0+ use NSForegroundColorAttributeName and NSShadowAttributeName respectively instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of how to do this in Swift:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes =
  [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"Exo2-Bold", size: 18) as! AnyObject,
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 3):

That crashes the app before UINavigationBar doesn't have a title or state... Those are UIButton methods

You need

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I think that's to tint the bar itself. We're already using the setBackgroundImage: method to change the navigation bar background, so I now need to change the text color from white to dark gray so that it is legible.

Comment: Sorry didn't know you were trying to set the navBar text color. thought you were just trying to change its color.

Answer (score 2):

The @RyJ answer is great and worked for me. Thought I'd chip in that there's a good tutorial on this in Ray Wenderlich's site, titled (excuse the pun):

[User Interface Customization in iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6)

See the section **Customizing UINavigationBar**

Here's the code snippet for the navigation bar title, to change globally:

```
// Customize the title text for *all* UINavigationBars
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
  UITextAttributeTextColor,
  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],
  UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
  UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:0.0],
  UITextAttributeFont,
  nil]];
```

One other minor point is that it seems there's a default shadow on the title bar, so to get rid of it, you can't just remove the attribute. Instead you have to set a shadow offset:

```
UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset : [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

for iOS 15

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = <PREFERRED BACKGROUND COLOR>
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : <PREFERRED TITLE COLOR>]
navigationBar.tintColor = <PREFERED TINT COLOR> //for bar buttons
navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to change the title bar's color.

```
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);

NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                            NSShadowAttributeName:shadow};

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleTextAttributes];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modern syntax and code that actually runs, this is how to globally style your `UINavigationBar` title text:

```
NSShadow *navigationBarTitleShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
navigationBarTitleShadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5
                                                         alpha:0.5];
navigationBarTitleShadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                                        NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT"
                                                                                              size:30.0],
                                                        NSShadowAttributeName : navigationBarTitleShadow }];
```

Note: `NSShadow`'s `shadowBlurRadius` property is not respected.

Note: Shadows are so iOS 6. Don't ever use them.