# Unable to customize UINavigationBar's appearance in iOS SDK:

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, background, uinavigationbar

I am trying to customize the appearance of the navigation var, which appears A couple of times thru my app (FYI: I am using storyboards). For some reason, Th app doesn't work (It gets stuck in the line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

in the main.m file, saying "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".

The code I wrote is this:

```
UIImage * TabBarBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarBG.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:TabBarBG];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:TabBarBG];
```

The customization of the tab bar works perfectly by the way, and I have tried it with a different picture for the NavBar, But its not here for simplicity sake!

the code above is found in a method called "customizeInterface" of the appDelegate class, and it is called from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the same class (appDelegate).

Any Idea as for why that might happen and what can I do to make it work?

Any comments appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't get "stuck", UIApplicationMain returns when the application exits abnormally, which breaks the run loop.  What's the log print?

Comment: 2012-07-05 18:37:41.324 SocialNow[797:f803] -[_UIAppearance setBackgroundImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d42930
2012-07-05 18:37:41.326 SocialNow[797:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearance setBackgroundImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d42930'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13c9022 0x155acd6 0x13cacbd 0x132fed0 0x132fcb2 0x2bea 0x2997 0x11386 0x12274 0x21183 0x21c38 0x15634

Comment: 0x12b3ef5 0x139d195 0x1301ff2 0x13008da 0x12ffd84 0x12ffc9b 0x11c65 0x13626 0x290d 0x2875)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UINavigationBar's appearance API does not support a method named `setBackgroundImage:`.  It does, however support a method named `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`. So try:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:TabBarBG forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, here's how you can change the navigation bar title and shadow color (if it conflicts with your new background image):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11005059/215845